# DataFlavor custom class usage

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I want to create a custom dataFlavor with my class (Item.class)

```
@Override
public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {                
    DataFlavor itemFlavor = new DataFlavor(Item.class, Item.class.getSimpleName());               
    try{
        System.out.println(dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(itemFlavor));
    }catch(UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Item.class

```
public class Item {
    private String classFile;
    private String imgFile;
    private String imgPath;    

    public Item(String classFile, String imgFile, String imgPath){
        this.classFile = classFile;
        this.imgFile = imgFile;
        this.imgPath = imgPath;
    }

    public String getImgFile() {
        return imgFile;
    }

    public void setImgFile(String imgFile) {
        this.imgFile = imgFile;
    }   

    public String getClassFile() {
        return classFile;
    }

    public void setClassFile(String classFile) {
        this.classFile = classFile;
    }

    public String getImgPath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    public void setImgPath(String imgPath) {
        this.imgPath = imgPath;
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error: `java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: Item`

**Can you say what is wrong ?**

I were using this docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dataflavor.html

Example, that demonstrate the problem [DND Test Project](https://github.com/NickEnbachtov/DNDProject)

To get an error, try drag from JTable to JLayeredPane

Comment: Based on your error, it's most likely that the data flavour to export the data in the first place doesn't include yours

Comment: Yes, I know, but how to include my class ?

Comment: I don't know, how is the data been exported?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Data was exported by drag and drop. When I use `DataFlavor.stringFlavor` I'm getting system out: **objectleveldesigner.Item@14f63e65**

Comment: @NikolayYenbakhtov Dragged from where?

Comment: Dragged from `JTable` row

Comment: I've created a simple project that demonstrate the problem. You can download it here [Test DND Project](https://github.com/NickEnbachtov/DNDProject)

Comment: To get an error, try drag from JTable to JLayeredPane